# Unity saving mesh dynamically and setting it dynamically

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization, mesh

I'm using Unity Editor with C# as programming language.

My question consists of two parts. In my situation I'm trying to save everything in my scene into a JSON file. And then loading it in a new Scene for reasons. You could read this question to get a general idea why: [Unity save everything (snapshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676534/unity-save-everything-snapshot)

So I'm trying to save my mesh in scene one. Then I have scene two which is empty and I'm trying to load it from scratch from a JSON file. I need to save something of the mesh so I can point at it when I load the objects in the new scene.

My current idea of saving:
I need to split because for example I have a sphere object, I get "Sphere Instance" when calling the name variable. The split will remove the " Instance" part.

```
    mesh = meshfilter.mesh.name.Split(' ')[0];
    sharedMesh = meshfilter.sharedMesh.name.Split(' ')[0];
```

So now in my JSON file I have "Sphere". So my next step is to build the new scene from scratch with this information.

So I use this code:

```
    meshFilter.mesh = Resources.Load(mesh) as Mesh;
    meshFilter.sharedMesh = Resources.Load(sharedMesh) as Mesh;
```

Unfortunately the resources.load will be null. In my test I use primitive and custom meshes.

Hopefully one of you can see what's wrong or tell me of a better way to save/load which works with the situation described.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why are you saving a mesh? Is the mesh generated during gameplay or does it exist already?

Comment: In this case, make sure you have a `"Sphere"` prefab in your `Resources` folder.

Comment: @Programmer the mesh already exists, I need a reference to the correct Mesh

Comment: @Iggy thanks for the suggestion I'll try it out!

Comment: ok. is the mesh a prefab or a model file? a screenshot would be helpful