# Dynamically serialize List to JSON using reflection in Unity

Tags: c#, json, list, unity-game-engine, reflection

I'm having a quite complex situation in which I would like some advice to solve this situation. So I asked this question earlier: [Unity save everything (snapshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676534/unity-save-everything-snapshot)

And I'm currently trying to serialize everything into JSON. Whilst serializing everything I have a few requirements.

1. I do not know which components are attached to a gameobject.
2. I do not know what these components (classes) have for properties/fields.

I succeeded in serializing the basic types of unity (transform/meshrenderer etc). However I'm now working on code to serialize custom components. For this I use reflection. This code works if a class only has primary types (string,int,float, etc). However I still face two challenges.

1. Serializing a list without knowing it's type (or at least knowing the type but unable to dynamically cast it with my knowledge)
2. Serializing fields that contain custom classes (and lists which contains custom classes).

For now I would like to get advice primarily on point one. I developed this code:
Type is as string that I got earlier

```
if (type.Contains("List"))
{
    value = serializeListVariable(singular.GetValue(comp));
}
```

Then here is the method which should serialize the list. With debugging I can see the objects are in the values variable. However they are not convertednvert them to JSON and just returns {}. In this first iteration I would like to dynamically save lists of primary types. But later I would like to do this with custom classes as well. If I do tostring with getvalues I'm able to get a correct JSON string afterwards, But then again I don't have influence on the tostring method of these custom classes...

```
private string serializeListVariable(object listobject)
{
    PropertyInfo listitems = listobject.GetType().GetProperty("Item");
    int listcount = (int)listobject.GetType().GetProperty("Count").GetValue(listobject, null);
    var values =  new object[listcount];
    for (int i =0; i < listcount; i++) {

        values[i] = listitems.GetValue(listobject, new object[] { i });
    }
    string serializedlist = JsonHelper.ToJson(values);
    return serializedlist;
}
```

The JSON helper method that is called:

```
public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
{
    Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
    wrapper.Items = array;
    return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
}
```

And the wrapper class that is mentioned:

```
[Serializable]
private class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T[] Items;
}
```

Hopefully some of you know to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried json.net ? It will convert the current state of a class (with parameters and their values) into a json via reflection. And you can deserialize the json back into the object.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! unfortunately unity doesn't support this :(

Comment: I've used it in unity for so many projects :) It works like cheese... get it from asset store

Comment: I tried that and it works for primitive types. Unfortunately It doesn't for custom classes.

Comment: Ofcourse it works for them! It works for even subtypes and inherited classes. Tried and tested

Comment: I'm trying to do this: string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listobject); It gives me a nullreference error unfortunately. With the debugger I can see that the object is not null or it's variables though. Could you perhaps give an example with a custom class? And thanks for all the help you already gave!

Comment: You can find examples here : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm

Apparently, Unity now provides this inbuilt, see here :
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html
However I'm not sure if it allows for retaining type and assembly references.

Answer (score 0):

Use LitJSON plugin in Unity.

```
return JsonMapper.ToJson(anyClassOrList);
```

Comment: I tried the LitJSON plugin and it works for primitive types. Not for custom classes unfortunately.